# Get some extra details from another page for each list item using Scrapy framework

Tags: scrapy

I have managed to parse the list of advertisements, put some information in `AdvertItem` and load this item using `AdvertLoader`. But I could not figure out how I can get some extra information about each advertisement from item page details, put this additional information in the same `AdvertItem` object and then load the item with all information using `AdvertLoader`.

```
class AdvertLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip, remove_tags)
    default_output_processor = Join()


class AdvertSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "adverts"
    start_urls = [
        "http://blablaadverts.com/",
    ]
    adverts_list_xpath = '//table[@class="object-list-table"]/tbody/tr[@class="object-type-apartment"]'
    advert_item_fields = {
        'id': './@id',
        'link': './/td[@class="object-name"]/h2[contains(@class, "object-title")]/a/@href',
        'status': 'normalize-space(.//td[contains(@class, "object-media")]/div/p/a/span[contains(@class, '
              '"sold-overlay-list")]/span/text())',
        'state': './/td[@class="object-name"]/h2[contains(@class, "object-title")]/a/text()',
        'city': './/td[@class="object-name"]/h2[contains(@class, "object-title")]/a/text()',
        'zone': './/td[@class="object-name"]/h2[contains(@class, "object-title")]/a/text()',
        'address': './/td[@class="object-name"]/h2[contains(@class, "object-title")]/a/text()',
        'rooms': './/td[contains(@class, "object-rooms")]/text()',
        'area': 'normalize-space(.//td[contains(@class, "object-m2")]/text())',
        'price': 'normalize-space(.//td[contains(@class, "object-price")]/p/text())',
    }
    advert_details_xpath = '//table[contains(@class, "object-data-meta")]/tbody/tr'
    advert_item_details_fields = {
        'floor': './/td/text()',
        'built_in_year': './/td/text()',
        'condition': './/td/text()',
        'ownership': './/td/text()',
        'energy_level': './/td/text()',
    }
    contact_name = '//div[contains(@class, "object-article-contact")]/p[@class="fn"]/text()'
    next_page = '//li[contains(@class, "next")]/a/@href'


    def parse(self, response):
            selector = Selector(response)

            for advert in selector.xpath(self.adverts_list_xpath):
                loader = AdvertLoader(AdvertItem(), selector=advert)

                for field, xpath in self.advert_item_fields.iteritems():
                    loader.add_xpath(field, xpath)

                    # This request is not working as I expect.
                    yield scrapy.Request("http://blablaadverts.com/index.htmlnr=55&search_key=ca41231a29d2ab921aed02e864152c0e",
                                     callback=self.parse_page2, meta={'loader': loader})

                    yield loader.load_item()

            next_page = response.xpath(self.next_page).extract_first()
            if next_page is not None:
                next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
                yield Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)


    def parse_page2(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        loader = response.meta['loader']  # type: AdvertLoader
        loader.selector = selector
        loader.add_xpath('contact_name', self.contact_name)
        # yield loader.load_item()
```

Below code saves only information about each advertisement without extra details from second item details page.

Function `parse_page2()` is working if I run it separately from `parse()` function.

How can I collect all information and only then load my `AdvertItem` object in loader?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I get you correctly or not.

But change this part of code

```
                # This request is not working as I expect.
                yield scrapy.Request("http://blablaadverts.com/index.htmlnr=55&search_key=ca41231a29d2ab921aed02e864152c0e",
                                 callback=self.parse_page2, meta={'loader': loader})

                yield loader.load_item()
```

to

```
                # This request is not working as I expect.
                scrapy.Request("http://blablaadverts.com/index.htmlnr=55&search_key=ca41231a29d2ab921aed02e864152c0e",
                                 callback=self.parse_page2, meta={'loader': loader})

                loader.load_item()
```

And then `yield` in this function when all information is available.

```
def parse_page2(self, response):
    selector = Selector(response)
    loader = response.meta['loader']  # type: AdvertLoader
    loader.selector = selector
    loader.add_xpath('contact_name', self.contact_name)
    yield loader.load_item()
```